# Rails Find and Include doesn't load a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm searching for users that match a set of tags. I want to return the tags matched and their linked profile. I can get the users with their linked tags, but not the profile. I've tried adding the :profile to the :include, but that doesn't work. I've tried putting the :profile in the :join, which works but only returns the first row.

Any suggestions?

```
# Returns only one record instead of the four it should
User.find(:all, :joins => :profile, :include => :skills, :conditions => { :tags => { :id => search_tags } } )

# Returns all four records that match but not their profiles
User.find(:all, :include => [:skills, :profile], :conditions => { :tags => { :id => search_tags } } )
```

**Update**
It turns out my data seeder didn't have Facebook data seeded for all users. So the second find actually works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
User.where(:tags => { :id => search_tags }).includes([:skills, :profile])
```

Comment: That worked. I also realized that my seeder put bad data that didn't have a profile with it...

Comment: Props for using the new ActiveRecord notation. I don't think the `[...]` square brackets are strictly necessary in the `includes(...)` method, though. Syntax pollution.

Answer (score 0):

If your models are linked you don't need to get the profiles with the find method. Once you had the Users you can always call `@user.profile`